# Сборка системного приложения

Tags: android

Понадобилось сделать приложение, но не хватает доступа к SDK. Требуется сделать системное приложение типа KingRoot или SuperSU. Это возможно, так как такие приложения есть. Они устанавливаются как обычные, а потом внедряются в систему. Как такое повторить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто так взять и поменять системые файлы нельзя. И тут есть два способа.

первый способ, законный. Вы собираете свою сборку андроида. В этом случае можно поменять много, очень много. Главное, что бы оно потом запустилось. Так делают многие производители телефонов.

второй способ, полузаконный. Этот способ заключается в том, что нужно вначале получить права рута. И тут опять два способа. Либо используется su (например, от sudosu, который Вы упомянули), либо рута нужно получить через какую то уязвимость. Всякие программы для рутания так и работают - вначале через уязвимость получают временного рута, а потом подменяют нужные файлы для постоянного эффекта.

Имея права рута, можно менять много чего, очень много. И нужно быть аккуратным.

Также следует отметить, что большинство подобных приложений пишется не на java, а на с/с++.  (хотя в целом, подобные приложения, это смесь java и с кода.).

Обсуждение конкретных уязвимостей, которые помогут получить рут на телефоне выходит за пределы допустимых тем на этом сайте.

Comment: я знаю что такое рут и уже лет 5 его юзаю) не подскажете, смогу ли я модифицировать системное приложение тогда? или может посмотреть как оно устроено и сделать наподобие?

Comment: я не знаю, сможете ли Вы модифицировать системное приложение:) я не знаю уровня Ваших сил и что за приложение Вы решили модифицировать.

Comment: смогу) ладно, обьясню. мне требуется сделать приложение для ввода кода разлочки сети (NCK) и, его отправки. Также с получением оставшихся попыток ввода

Comment: смогу) ладно, обьясню. мне требуется сделать приложение для ввода кода разлочки сети (NCK) и, его отправки. Также с получением оставшихся попыток ввода. Приложение будет для одной модели, делается только для нее. Если конкретнее - это повтор приложения EM SIM ME Lock. Дело в том, что оно включается в инженерное меню на устройством с процессором МТК. У нашей модельки не такой.  Я декомпилировал system/framework/telephony-common.jar  -  classes.dex  и нашем методы, которые остались после перепрошивки. ВООБЩЕМ. Нужно разобрать какое-нибудь приложение, посмотреть как оно устроено и повторить это

Comment: это возможно?))

Comment: раз это написал один человек, значит всегда может написать другой, вопрос только времени и денег. Думаю, что правильный подход будет в создании своей прошивки.

Comment: нет, я уже дал отличный старт, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

создатели SuperSU решали эту проблему, пожалуй, несколько лет. У вас вряд ли получится сделать быстрее.

В общих чертах - система от каждого производителя имеет ряд *дыр*, по-научному называемых *эксплойтами*.
Используя эти эксплойты, подобные программы выполняют определенный код, который позволяет им получить доступ к файловой системе со всеми разрешениями.

Я уверен, что они не поделятся реализацией, т. к. она была выработана вследствии больших затрат времени и денег.

Comment: а тогда возможно ли модифицировать какое-нибудь системное приложение? Прошивка деодекс

Comment: @СергейГрушин, на уже установленной прошивке - если только у вас есть рут права.

Comment: тогда хорошо) спасибо)